# Is it possible to have more than 64 member in OptionSet?

Tags: ios, swift

Based on https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optionset , I notice that it is not possible to have more than 64 members in `OptionSet`

For instance

```
struct Options: OptionSet {
    let rawValue: Int


    static let options0 = Options(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    static let options1 = Options(rawValue: 1 << 1)
    static let options2 = Options(rawValue: 1 << 2)
    static let options3 = Options(rawValue: 1 << 3)
    // ...
    // ...
    // ...
    static let options63 = Options(rawValue: 1 << 63)
    
    // rawValue = 0
    static let options64 = Options(rawValue: 1 << 64)
    // rawValue = 0
    static let options65 = Options(rawValue: 1 << 65)
}

let options: Options = [.options64]

precondition(!options.contains(.options65))
```

For the above code example, the set shouldn't contain option65 as it is not inserted initially.

However, since both `1 << 64` and `1 << 65` ended up as 0, this will yield wrong result.

I was wondering, is this the limitation of `OptionSet` of not able to have more than 64 members? Or, there is a workaround?

Comment: Each option is mapped to a bit, since we are dealing with a 64 bit architecture, that is the limit to the number of members.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `OptionSet` needs to implement the methods

```
mutating func formUnion(_ other: Self)
mutating func formIntersection(_ other: Self)
mutating func formSymmetricDifference(_ other:Self)
```

from the `SetAlgebra` protocol, and the operator

```
static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
```

from the `Equatable` protocol.

If the `rawValue` is a type that conforms to the `FixedWidthInteger` protocol then the standard library provides default implementations for all these requirements. So one option (as [suggested by Sweeper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74002876/1187415)) is to use an integer type with more than 64 bits.

But actually not the full power of `FixedWidthInteger` is needed for `OptionSet`, only the bitwise AND, OR, and XOR operations. So here is another possible solution:

First define a protocol for the required bitwise operations:

```
protocol BitwiseOperators {
    static func | (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    static func & (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    static func ^ (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    static var allZeros: Self { get }
}
```

(*Remark:* There used to be a `BitwiseOperation` protocol in Swift 3, but that does not exist anymore.)

Next we define default implementations for all required `OptionSet` methods if the raw value conforms to the `BitwiseOperators` type:

```
extension OptionSet where RawValue: BitwiseOperators & Equatable {
    
    init() {
        self.init(rawValue: RawValue.allZeros)
    }
    
    mutating func formUnion(_ other: Self) {
        self = Self(rawValue: self.rawValue | other.rawValue)
    }
    
    mutating func formIntersection(_ other: Self) {
        self = Self(rawValue: self.rawValue & other.rawValue)
    }
    
    mutating func formSymmetricDifference(_ other:Self) {
        self = Self(rawValue: self.rawValue ^ other.rawValue)
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        lhs.rawValue == rhs.rawValue
    }
}
```

Now, in order to define an option set with more than 64 possible options, we need a raw value type which can store the necessary number of bits, and implements the AND, OR, and XOR operations. Here is an example for 128 bits, but it can easily be extended to any necessary size:

```
struct Raw128: Equatable, BitwiseOperators {
    let lo: UInt64
    let hi: UInt64
    
    static func | (lhs: Raw128, rhs: Raw128) -> Raw128 {
        Raw128(lo: lhs.lo | rhs.lo, hi: lhs.hi | rhs.hi)
    }
    
    static func & (lhs: Raw128, rhs: Raw128) -> Raw128 {
        Raw128(lo: lhs.lo & rhs.lo, hi: lhs.hi & rhs.hi)
    }
    
    static func ^ (lhs: Raw128, rhs: Raw128) -> Raw128 {
        Raw128(lo: lhs.lo ^ rhs.lo, hi: lhs.hi ^ rhs.hi)
    }
    
    static var allZeros: Raw128 { Raw128(lo: 0, hi: 0) }
}
```

As a convenience we can define an initializer which sets exactly one bit at a given position:

```
extension Raw128 {
    init(bitPos: Int) {
        switch bitPos {
        case 0..<64:    lo = 1 << bitPos; hi = 0
        case 64..<128:  lo = 0; hi = 1 << (bitPos - 64)
        default: fatalError("`bit` must be in the range 0...127")
        }
    }
}
```

Finally we can define the `Options` options set with `Raw128` as the raw value type:

```
struct Options: OptionSet {
    let rawValue: Raw128

    init(rawValue: Raw128) {
        self.rawValue = rawValue
    }
    
    static let options0 = Options(rawValue: RawValue(bitPos: 0))
    static let options1 = Options(rawValue: RawValue(bitPos: 1))
    static let options2 = Options(rawValue: RawValue(bitPos: 2))
    // ...
    static let options63 = Options(rawValue: RawValue(bitPos: 63))
    static let options64 = Options(rawValue: RawValue(bitPos: 64))
    static let options65 = Options(rawValue: RawValue(bitPos: 65))
}
```

and everything works as expected:

```
let options: Options = [.options64]
print(!options.contains(.options65)) // true
```

Comment: Huh, I didn't know doing a default implementation of `SetAlgebra` would be this simple! I thought it had a lot more requirements than just `Equatable` + the 3 set operations.

Comment: @Sweeper: I just tried to mimic [`extension OptionSet where RawValue: FixedWidthInteger`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/OptionSet.swift#L333) from the standard library. Apparently `OptionSet` has default implementations for some of the `SetAlgebra` methods. One can also start with an "empty" implementation `struct Options: OptionSet {}` and use the “Do you want to add protocol stubs?” fix-it in Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

Although Swift only provides fixed width integer types for up to 64 bits, [`OptionSet`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optionset) only requires that `RawValue` to be any kind of `FixedWidthInteger` for the default `SetAlgebra` implementations to be synthesised.

> When creating an option set, include a `rawValue` property in your type declaration. For your type to automatically receive default implementations for set-related operations, the `rawValue` property must be of a type that conforms to the `FixedWidthInteger` protocol, such as `Int` or `UInt8`.

Therefore, you can technically always create your `FixedWidthInteger` of arbitrary size, by combining smaller integers, and use it in an option set.

For example, [here](https://github.com/Jitsusama/UInt128) is a `UInt128` implementation I found. I can use it in an option set just like normal:

```
struct Foo: OptionSet {
    let rawValue: UInt128
    
    static let option1 = Foo(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    static let option2 = Foo(rawValue: 1 << 1)
    static let option3 = Foo(rawValue: 1 << 2)
    // ...
    static let option65 = Foo(rawValue: 1 << 64)
}

print([Foo.option1, .option65] as Foo) // Foo(rawValue: 18446744073709551617)
```

Though obviously, this is not going to be as fast as the natively supported integers, and admittedly, if someone hasn't already implemented the size you want, implementing a whole `FixedWidthInteger` just for an `OptionSet` isn't very practical.

Comment: Another option (!) is to use the `__uint128_t` type, as suggested here: https://forums.swift.org/t/128-bit-operations-in-swift/21639/2

Comment: @MartinR Maybe I'm just lazy, but conforming that to `FixedWidthInteger` looks like a lot of pain... I would rather just use a ready-made Swift package :P

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to mention it. – Actually only the bitwise AND, OR, and XOR operations are needed for an OptionSet. There used to be a [`protocol BitwiseOperations`](https://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/protocol/bitwiseoperations/), I wonder what happened with that.